# Как работать с docker на windows?

Tags: windows-10, docker

Что нужно: linux среда для комфортного создания контейнеров для своих проектов. Хотелось бы это делать максимально просто.

Теперь достаточно просто скачать установщик( у меня Win 10), Docker Toolbox  использовать не нужно ?

Есть несколько вопросов (возможно они немного банальные):
Т.к. работа происходит на виндовс, то нужна linux система, поверх которой уже будут установлены все нужные приложения - php, mysql, nginx etc.
Все это добро пакуется в image к которому дальше будут обращаться контейнеры.
Если что-то неверно - просьба поправить.

Где-то можно подсмотреть готовую конфигурацию или все нужно установить с нуля ?

Comment: Виртуальные машины вам в помощь

Comment: готовую конфигурацию чему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я работаю с `docker` на Windows 8. У нас много проектов с использованием `Vagrant` и `VirtualBox`, а недавно мы перешли на `docker`. Я где-то читал, что VirtualBox не живёт вместе с Hyper-V, поэтому мы используем `Docker Toolbox` и `VirtualBox`

Чтобы начать работать после установки `Docker Toolbox` и `VirtualBox`, нужно выполнить несколько шагов

1. Создать Docker Machine

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default
docker-machine start default
```

2. Настроить Docker Machine

   Содержимое результата выполнения команды `docker-machine env default` записать в переменные среды (в свойстваъх компьютера)

```
C:\>docker-machine env default
You can further specify your shell with either 'cmd' or 'powershell' with the --shell flag.

SET DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
SET DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
SET DOCKER_CERT_PATH=C:\Users\Пользователь\.docker\machine\machines\default
SET DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=default
SET COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=true
REM Run this command to configure your shell:
REM     @FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('"C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.EXE" env default') DO @%i
```

Например, здесь - 5 переменных от `DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY` до `COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS`

3. Опционально: добавить запись в файл `C:\WINDOWS\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` (`192.168.99.100` - это IP адрес из переменной `DOCKER_HOST`)

```
192.168.99.100      docker.local
```

Всё. Можно начинать работать =) И linux система не нужна, тут у вас небольшое недопонимание возникло: система будет крутиться внутри `docker`

Начать можно с простого файла `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "2.1"

services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
          - "80:80"
```

Создать его нужно обязательно в папке пользователя, например, в `C:\Users\Пользователь\Docker\Qwerty`. Точнее, это нужно делать в проектах, где файлы с хоста должны быть доступны внутри контейнера, в данном примере это требование не обязательное.

В папке с файлом `docker-compose.yml` запускаем команду `docker-compose up -d` и заходим в http://docker.local/. Там будет дефолтная страница `Nginx`

`Tips & Tricks`: Иногда случается так, что внутри контейнера как будто нет интернета. Тогда нужно сначала остановить `docker-machine stop`, а затем запустить заново `docker-machine start`

Дальше можно гуглить по слову `docker-compose nginx php mysql`

Comment: Не решали случайно проблему тормозов volumes windows && linux? 
Большие проекты с множеством файлов беспощадно тормозят на Windows : (

Comment: @zsiteru я так понял, что чем больше производится файловых операций из guest в host, тем всё медленнее работает. Я пробовал это сокращать путём переноса папок внутрь контейнера. Например, для проектов на Symfony есть 2 папки, которые потенциально можно "засунуть" в контейнер: это var и vendor. Обычно я прячу только var через добавление `.:/srv` и `/srv/var` в volumes (именно в этом порядке), cм. [пример](https://github.com/covex-nn/docker-workflow-symfony/blob/master/docker-compose.override.yml.dist)

Answer (score 1):

Docker toolbox качать не нужно.
Сам сталкиваться с этим, когда была 8-ка, искренне не мог понять в чем же дело

Десятка тоже нужна Windows 10 Pro. Иначе докер не будет работать. Но, я думаю, вы уже поняли это :)

Можете пройти туториалы на докере. Там эти моменты рассматриваются. 
[Вот тут](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/)

И еще, когда у меня были проблемы с докером, я тоже задавал тут вопрос, но ответ не получал...не берусь говорить, что на стэке этого не знают, но лучше идти на Stack на английском или искать ответ самому..